# Equivalent of enrichHeaders in spring-integration 5.1.1

Tags: spring-integration

The following code was written back in the 1.2.1 version of spring-integration-java-dsl

```
IntegrationFlows.from(inMessageChannel())//
                    .enrichHeaders(
                            c -> c.<InMessage>headerFunction(HEADER_IN_MESSAGE_ID,
                                    (message) -> message.getPayload().getInMessage().getId())//
                                    .<InMessage>headerFunction(HEADER_ORIGINAL_MESSAGE_ID,
                                            (message) -> message.getPayload().getInMessage().getMessageId()),
                            c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(100)//
                                    .transactional(platformTransactionManager)//
                                    .errorChannel(errorChannel())))//
                    .handle(...)
```

Details:
`inMessageChannel()` is a Pollable channel

`errorChannel()` is a SubscribableChannel

The `enrichHeaders()` function has changed since and I cannot find the equivalent code to write in the 5.1.1 version (spring-integration-core). While trying different approaches (among others, call enrichHeaders once for each Consumer or use the bridge method) I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A poller should not be specified for endpoint 'myFlow.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#1', since 'myFlow.channel#0' is a SubscribableChannel (not pollable).
```

If I understand the 1.2.1 code correctly, the poller was added to the `inMessageChannel()`, in the new version it tries to add the poller to the `errorChannel()` and this is not allowed.

Any ideas ?
Thank you !

PS: obviously I am a beginner in spring-integration that has to adapt some code :)

Answer (score 1):

Starting with version `5.0`, that `enrichHeaders()` has really been changed.
What we have done is just a merge of two `Consumer`s. So, currently you need to configure it like this:

```
        .enrichHeaders(
                        c -> c.<InMessage>headerFunction(HEADER_IN_MESSAGE_ID,
                                (message) -> message.getPayload().getInMessage().getId())//
                                .<InMessage>headerFunction(HEADER_ORIGINAL_MESSAGE_ID,
                                        (message) -> message.getPayload().getInMessage().getMessageId())
                                .poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(100)//
                                        .transactional(platformTransactionManager)//
                                        .errorChannel(errorChannel())))//
```

See more info in the Migration Guide: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/wiki/Spring-Integration-4.3-to-5.0-Migration-Guide#java-dsl-breaking-changes